# How to enable root login Ubuntu snappy core?

Tags: mount, permissions, password, ubuntu-core, snap

I want to enable root login for snappy ubuntu OS but root file system is mounted in Read Only mode. I tried so many ways to moun it in Read/Write mode but no success. 
When I execute sudo passwd command response like below

passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
  passwd: password unchanged

I think it's only because of no write permission in root file system. 
I tried commands like 
            sudo mount -o remount,rw /

still its not mounted in R/W mode.
Please help..

Comment: I wanted to enable root login for SSH connection. I don't want to use sudo keyword in each command.

Comment: Why not just log into the root shell with `sudo su -` from the normal user?

Comment: No, I want to run some commands remotely like winrm and wsman. So it needs root privileges.

Comment: I  want to confirm whether root file system can be mounted in R/ W  mode in snappy Ubuntu core?

Comment: I'm afraid not-- it's backed by a squashfs image, which is by definition read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the nail on the head: Ubuntu Core mounts the root filesystem as ***squashfs*** which is read-only.  All the **DEFAULT** user authentication files /etc/***passwd***, /etc/***shadow***, /etc/***group*** and /etc/***gshadow*** all live on a read-only filesystem.  By Snapcraft's **DESIGN** you can't modify these users.

Only users added with:

```
sudo adduser --extrausers testusername
```

Can be modified by the `passwd` command.  The ***root*** user is not one of these.  The user authentication files for these supplemental users live in a different path which **IS** RW:

```
/writable/system-data/var/lib/extrausers/
```

Where you'll find writable user authentication files which can be altered by the `passwd` command.

**NOTE:** There is a way of working with System users in the following link, but I'm not sure you'll be able to alter the `root` user which is your goal:

https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/manage-devices/

### WORKAROUND:

Preface the remote command with `sudo`:

```
ssh yourUser@1.2.3.4 -t 'sudo /bin/sh -c cd /home/yourUser;sudo ./test.sh'
```

In ***test.sh*** you can specify commands which require root perms and the `sudo` will execute them successfully.  I guess there's other ways of doing it, but it's a starting point.  HTH bud-  T